# How to Update/Set Field values by LookUpId in a sharepoint list?

Tags: list, client-object-model, sharepoint-server, lookup-column

I have a list called `ResourceCheckList` which contains following `columns` with `lookup fields` as below :

[image]

Here `Resource:ID` is a `lookup column` which contains `unique ID` of another list.

So, I want to update `CubeOffice` to `No` where `Resource:ID` == `14`

**My code:**

```
function lookup(){

var cc = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = cc.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ResourceCheckList');
var listitem = list.getItemById(14); <-- i think this statement goes wrong

listitem.set_item('CubeOffice',false);
listitem.update();
cc.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerysucceeded611),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed11));
}
function onQuerysucceeded611(){
alert('donelook');
}
function onQueryFailed11(sender, args){
alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**Design:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="btnlookup" value="lookup" onclick="lookup()"></input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```